# How to embed a View (with Buttons, etc.) inside an EditText?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to figure out how to embed things, *other* than Drawables, inside an EditText widget. Specifically the example I'm thinking of is from the Google Buzz widget:

[screenshot](http://greydream.org/pics/buzz.png)
(no inline image, sorry, I'm a newb)

It appears to the casual observer that there's an entire layout object pinned to the bottom of the EditText, containing an ImageView, a TextView, and a Button.

Anyone have any idea how to pull this off? Or do we think this is a custom subclass of EditText?

Answer (score 15):

The EditText + Button + ... it's a FrameLayout with the EditText with fill_parent and the Buttons with layout_gravitiy:"bottom". Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- Main Layout (may be relative or whatever --> <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Layout for edittext and button -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="5"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="Overflow"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- More layouts ..... -->   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use frame layout for embed Button in EditText,here i give sample code for embed TextView  in EditText,just change the TextView as Button

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="40px"
        android:layout_y="35px"
        >        

    <EditText android:id="@+id/twt_post_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="320dp" android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:gravity="left" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:maxLength="140" android:ellipsize="end" />
            <TextView
                android:text="123" 
                android:paddingLeft="270dp"      
                android:paddingTop="100dp"   
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/twt_content_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:layout_gravity="center"              
                android:background="@color/transparent"/>    
                </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what they have done here is create a background for their layout that looks like an EditText.  Then they added an EditText with the background turned off and come Buttons.

Comment: I suppose that's possible, though if you play with the focus chain with the trackball, it doesn't seem like that's the case.