# How to disable setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) in android?

Tags: android, textview, linkmovementmethod

I am using  setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())  for textview in my app. Now i want to enable long item click and item click to select chats to delete/ copy similar to whats app.In that case i dont want the link to open when i click on textview as the selection process is in progress.
Also once i deselect it , should again have movement method back.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574005/disable-setmovementmethodlinkmovementmethod-getinstance-on-android

Comment: not working.  So i have chat on both side sender and receiver. So right now selection is enabled for sender only, so when i click on receiver chat(other party) , how to notify that selection is in process...all these are inflated in recycler view.Since i dont allow selection of other person chat... those layout are not notified.